# Parameterless stored procedure to update insert

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, insert-update

I am working on a stored procedure that is supposed to insert or update rows in a remote table. I tried to use MERGE, but it is not possible to use MERGE when the target table is a remote.

Can someone show me how can I also do the update within the sproc? Do I need to first read the records into a temp table and then compare the values? The column value I am interested in updating is FlagValue.

**UPDATE**

I was able to create a linked server on the other server and flipped the target and source.

I am putting together a stored procedure that uses MERGE, I was wondering if someone could help me review the code and let me know if it looks ok. The code basically has to update the FlagValue column if the sku already resides in the target table but the FlagValue value is different, and it has to insert records that are also limited to the SELECT inside the USING () as SOURCE, and not insert all records from the table product.

**UPDATED T-SQL:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[mn_RecordInfo_Upsert]
AS
BEGIN

    --Synchronize the target table with refreshed data from source table
    MERGE [dbo].[RecordInfo] AS [t]
    USING
        ( SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
            [p].[ProductID]
          , [p].[Flag]
          FROM
            [server].[db].[dbo].[Product] [p]  -- Remote linked server table
          WHERE
            (
              [Category] = 2
              OR [Description] = 'This type of product' )
            AND LEN([ProductID]) = 10
            AND [ProductID] LIKE 'P0%'
          ORDER BY
            [Date] DESC
        ) AS [s]
    ON ( [t].[PID] = [s].[ProductID] ) 

    --When records are matched, update the records if there is any change
    WHEN MATCHED AND [t].[Flag] <> [s].[Flag]
        AND [t].[PID] = [s].[ProductID] THEN
        UPDATE SET
               [t].[Flag] = [s].[Flag]                          

    --When no records are matched, insert the incoming records from source table to target table
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT
               (
                 [PID]
               , [Flag] )
        VALUES (
                 [s].[ProductID]
               , [s].[Flag] )       

    --SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
    OUTPUT
        $action AS [DMLAction]
      , [inserted].*
      , [deleted].*;
END;
```

Thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: A solution is to create the stored procedure on the remote server.  Then you can use `MERGE`.

Comment: What UPDATE?  Show us the Update that you want to execute.

Comment: I just added it. My bad.

Comment: If you want to update on the remote server then use 4 part name

Comment: What I want to know is how to differentiate if the operation that needs to take place is an INSERT, or an UPDATE.

Comment: If you can use the idea that @Eric suggested, create an SP on the remote server and use merge

Comment: I wish I could but I do not have the access to create a linked server on that server so that using MERGE would be possible.

Comment: I was able to add the linked server. and create the SP on the remote server. I am updating my t-sql, something is not working, even though the select statement used as the SOURCE returns only about 2100+ rows, when I execute the stored procedure, all the records from the product table (source) are getting inserted into the target table.

Comment: Have you confirmed your `USING ...` returns any row?  If not, then everything is inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question to just be what you've written does what you think it does? I believe it does. Your update looks fine, although joining  `target.sku = source.sku` again is redundant. All the different statements in a single merge statement (e.g. `when matched`, `when not matched by source`, `when not matched by target`) will use the join criteria declared at the top, so you don't need to specify it again. One other thing to consider is if `FlagValue` can be null. If so, checking that `target.FlagValue != source.FlagValue` will return false since `null != null`.

As for your insert, you are correct. It will only use the results of the subquery you defined and aliased as `source` (side note, althought MSDN likes to alias them `source` and `target`, i tend to like `s` and `t` since they're not reserved keywords and avoids confusion when you utlimately end up using `source` and `target` as *actual* keywords when you type, for instance, `when not matched by target`. The point is, you can alias them whatever you want; you're not restricted to those two keywords).

If you want visibility into what's going on during the execution, you can do two main things. The first is to use an `OUTPUT` clause at the end; something as simple as

```
...
(
     [SOURCE].[SKU],
     [SOURCE].[FlagValue]
)
output $action as DMLAction, inserted.*, deleted.*
```

If you're finding `MERGE` clunky to work with, the second approach would be to consider writing these as two separate statements instead of a `MERGE`; an `insert`, and an `update`. For the most part, a `MERGE` does that anyway, so you're not losing out on peformance, and it's usually easier to pick apart an `insert` or `update` statement than a `merge` in my experience.

Also, I have to give an obligatory word of caution when joining across a linked server. Sometimes it will perform fine, but sometimes it will do it's own thing entirely. If the remote table is big, you could potentially end up scanning the entire table and piping it across the linked server, even if you wouldn't expect it to get anything close to a plan that bad were the table local.

Comment: Hi Xedni, I update my post with the last version of my code. I think it is doing what I need it to do. Thank you very much for your explanation.